# Label em laço no Foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, label

Estou com dificuldade de mostrar informações que vem de um objeto para mostrar em uma Label, retornando em forma de lista.

```
//Pegando os dados do Rest e armazenando na variável usuários

var usuario = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<ConsumeRoot>>().Result;

foreach (var a in usuario)
{
    lblTitulo.Text = a.titulo;
}
```

A label retorna somente uma informação, essa classe esta recebendo uma API que está recebendo informações de um banco de dados, são 6 informações que é para aparecer nessa label informa de pilha.

Comment: Além do erro do operador de atribuição, `Label` não é recomendada para mostrar listas, um controle como `BulletedList` (web forms), `ListBox`  (win forms) ou `ListView` (xamarin) seria mais apropriado

Comment: Jovem, percebi que vc está tentando aceitar as duas respostas como corretas. Você precisa escolher apenas uma para marcar. Se as duas te ajudaram, você pode votar positivamente nas duas, mas marcar como correta só é possível uma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em cada iteração deste foreach, você está substituindo a informação anterior, talvez você esteja esquecendo de concatenar os resultados:

```
    foreach (var a in usuario)
    {
        lblTitulo.Text += a.titulo + " ";
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Acontece que o valor do label está sendo **substituído** a cada laço.

Faça a concatenação dos valores ou então use `string.Join` e faça apenas uma atribuição

```
var usuario = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<ConsumeRoot>>().Result;

lblTitulo.Text = string.Join(", ", usuario.Select(u => u.Titulo));
```